# Power BI Cumulative Sum by Dimension Table

Tags: powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum, datamodel

I want to cumulatively sum up cost:

I have a cost table

[image]

And a date table

[image]

They are connected via the DateKey.

I have written the following measure in the Cost Table:

```
Cumulative Total = 
CALCULATE (
SUM(Cost[Cost]),
FILTER (
ALL( Cost[Date] ),
'Cost'[Date] <= MAX (Cost[Date] )
)
)
```

The problem seems to be that I want to use the dimension table Date in the visual.
When I use the Date from the cost table to sum up it works, but as soon as I use the Dates from the Date table, the result is sum and not cumulative.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `ALL( Cost[Date] )` with `ALL(Cost)`

```
Cumulative Total = 
  CALCULATE(
    SUM(Cost[Cost]),
    FILTER( ALL(Cost), Cost[Date] <= MAX(Cost[Date]) ) 
  )
```